# finally: txt.close() SyntaxError in Python

Tags: python, finally

I can not use finally:txt.close() to close a txt file. Please help me out. Thank you!

```
txt = open('temp5.txt','r')
for i in range(5):
    try:
        10/i-50
        print(i)
    except:
        print('error:', i)
        
finally:
    txt.close()
```

Error:

```
  File "C:\Users\91985\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_12240/2698394632.py", line 9
    finally:
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I was confused because this part was good without error:

```
txt = open('temp5.txt','r')
for i in range(5):
    try:
        10/i-50
        print(i)
    except:
        print('error:', i)
```

Output:

```
error: 0
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: the indentation of finally is wrong in the code snipped. 
It needs to be in the same column as try and except

Comment: Did you mean to use a context manager in the form: `with open('temp5.txt','r') as txt:` to automatically close the file?

Comment: The indentation is flawed. Also, what were you hoping *10/i-50* would do (apart from raising a ZeroDivisionError exception)?

Comment: The indentation you show implies the existence of a `for/finally` construct. This does not exist in python hence the syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `try` and `except` blocks exist only in your `for loop` and are executed for every iteration of the loop. Because of this, your `finally` block will not work as it has no `try` or `except` part. If you want to close the file after the loop, you can omit the `finally` block and just have `txt.close()` after the for loop:

```
txt = open('temp5.txt','r')
for i in range(5):
    try:
        10/i-50
        print(i)
    except:
        print('error:', i)
txt.close()
```

Additionally, you could also open the file using `with` to close it automatically:

```
with open("temp5.txt") as txt:
    for i in range(5):
        try:
            10/i-50
            print(i)
        except:
            print('error:', i)
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you really need using `open()` and `close()`? I suggest you to use context managers, that will make your life easier:

```py
with open("temp5.txt") as file:
    # Logic, exception handling, ...
```